# Yii model rules() method doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii-validation

Hi have a problem with the rules() method of one of my application model.

#### Here is rules():

```
public function rules() 
{ 
  $newRules = array(
    array('password_verification', 'required'),
    array('password_verification', 'length', 'min'=>6, 'max'=>32),
    array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password_verification'),
    array('username, email', 'length', 'min'=>3,'max'=>255),
    array('password', 'length','min'=>6, 'max'=>32),
    array('username, email', 'unique'),
    array('email', 'email'),
    array('valid_until_formated','compare', 
          'compareAttribute'=>'valid_from_formated','operator'=>'>'),
    array('id, type,username, password, password_verification, email, valid_from, valid_until, valid_until_formated, valid_from_formated, added_on, created_by','safe'),
  );
}
```

(sorry for the format of the code).

#### And here is the problem:

I want to test if "valid_until_formated" is greater than "valid_from_formated".

When I submit my form with wrong values (valid_from greater than vali_ until) I get an error message, I can see it on firebug but the values are inserted in data base.

But for instance if I try with a username already used or a password with fewer character than 6 then I have an error and nothing is created in database?

Does anybody have an idea why this rule doesn't work (even if I get an error message) ?
(this is the format of valid_until_formated, for example: "20121118" )

Thanks for reading me and sorry for my approximate English.

Have a good day :)

Michaël

Comment: Can we see the rest of your rules() function?  Do you return $newRules or is there any other processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks you all for your answer.

Actually it was a dump mistake I did.

I didn't know the validate() method was call by the save() one. Actually I was trying to save a User and I didn't understand why the rules in my CustomUser model were not run -*_*-.

The test was on my User:rules() and my CustomUser::rules() inherits my User::rules()...Anyway I fixed this issue like that.

> if(myCustomUser->validate()){
>
> myUser = new User;
>
> ... ...
>
> myUser->save(false);
>
> }

Like that I can create a user with the validation rules of my CustomUser.

Thanks, Have a nice day :)

Comment: You really should mark your own answer as correct.  Marking the other answer as correct will lead to others thinking that compare is backwards, as opposed to the real issue (you were using two different models)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the comparison between your values isn't working as expected.

Per the [CCompareValidator.php file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/validators/CCompareValidator.php):

```
case '>':
    if($value<=$compareValue)
    {
            $message=$this->message!==null?$this->message:Yii::t('yii','{attribute} must be greater than "{compareValue}".');
            $this->addError($object,$attribute,$message,array('{compareAttribute}'=>$compareTo,'{compareValue}'=>$compareValue));
    }
    break;
```

Looks like your comparison is backwards according to the way this works.  What happens if you flip your `'>'` to `'<'`?

Comment: Yes, could be :-)  But his code isn't working with what he's got.  At the least, he can run that if statement with his values to double-check to see if things work.